# How to handle audio-card buffer

Tags: c++, audio, buffer, visualizer

Im trying to do a screen-flashing application that flashes the screen depending on the audio(like an audio visualizer, but instead of a visualization like bars or something like that, just flash the screen).

I already made the music player and know how to make the widget get full screen and change color(which will flash), but I dont know how to detect the (I think it's audio-card)buffer is full, because when it is full I would change the color of the widget, and this would be really super fast, so the screen flashes super quickly.
Any ideas on how to detect if the buffer is full, or any other approach I might pursue to achieve my goal?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the SoundMixer Class computeSpectrum method? It doesn't give you a buffer info rather it returns info about the sound being played that you can use in order to represent the sound graphically.

Comment: I haven't heard of it. Weird name SoundMixer Class computeSpectrum method, isnt it?

Comment: Sorry it was badly expressed! Check the computeSpectrum method of the SoundMixer class!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I chose the tag Flash meaning the screen-flash(I can't create new tags) not the language(which I know nothing about ;P), and my dad(which let me this assignment) says that Flash has limitations on speed of screen-flashing(he needs at least 30 flashes per second).